# Firefox: blocking pages from redirecting to another page

Tags: firefox

I am using Firefox (Iceweasel) 24.4.0. In the previous version, I have selected in the menu to block pages redirecting to another page. Now this option seems to have disappeared in the new version, and I cannot find it.

Also, when a page tries to redirect to another page, I only get the option to "allow" it, but I don't get the option to add the page to rules, so that I am not asked every time.

Are these options hidden in newer versions of Firefos? Can this be configured in another way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/noredirect/):

> NoRedirect lets the user take control of HTTP redirects. It can be used to interdict an >ISP's DNS search redirection hijacks, preview/screen "shortened" URLs (e.g., TinyURL), stop >the annoying redirection of "smart" error pages, etc.